# How can I center a box in CSS?

Tags: css, screen, resolution

I would like to know how can i center this box?

HTML Code:

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

CSS Code:

```
#box
{
  width : 30%;
  height : auto;
  overflow : auto ;
  border : 1px solid #C5C5C5;
  background : #F8F8F8;
  position : absolute;
  left : 33.6%;
  border-top : none;
  text-align : left;
  display : none;
}
```

Comment: Wait, why are you centering the box, if it's `display: none`?

Comment: when it appears i want to be centered

Comment: Take out `position` and `left`, then add `margin:auto;`

Comment: @mc10 this is the box that appears like that of google auto suggest but this is coded in php, mysql, and jquary. Now does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since #box is absolutely positioned, you would center it like so:

```
#box {
    left: 50%; /* centers #box in its containing element */
    margin-left: -15%; /* half the element's width (30%) */
}
```

Those properties are in addition to the ones you've set already.

The idea is to position #box's left edge in the center of its containing element (left: 50%), then move #box left by half its own width by giving it a negative margin (margin-left: -15%).

Answer (score 4):

Try the following CSS:

```css
#box
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px; /* Or some other width */
}
```

Comment: just make sure to give it a width, or `centered` is meaningless

Comment: @Shad He already declared `width : 30%;`, so it should be fine.

Comment: P does that mean you presume he imports his entire previous rule?

Comment: @Shad Yes; I only mean to add my rule to his.

Comment: sorry, to clarify, your rule tacked on to his, won't do anything useful (OP has position:absolute), and your rule alone also won't do anything useful (no width)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
.Box {
   background-color: lightgrey;
   width: 400px;
   border: 25px solid grey;
   padding: 25px;
   margin: 25px;
   align-content:center;
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -50px;
   margin-left: -100px;
}
```